# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=129742, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, arrays

I have a fragment which contains data to be sent to another activity. Sending and retrieving one extras from the intent is working but not for other byte array. Please look into it.

**Fragment class**

```
        String userId = profile.getId();
        Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(userId);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("name",name);
        myIntent.putExtra("image",byteArray);
        getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

**MAIN2ACTIVITY**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    byte[] byteArray = intent.getExtras().getByteArray("image");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

The third line main2activity throws error : Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=129742, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

This is seems to be the main error 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: Is this the only error ? Can you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: @varunkr may be this is the reason : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: yeah this is the main error

Comment: do you get the name extra crrectly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this..

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
 String name =bundle.getString("name");
    byte[] byteArray =getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
}
```

Tested It will surely help you...

Comment: Besides the null checking, what makes it different?

Comment: @trigger..here..null checking is the main...i want to make it bold when posting the answer

Comment: @trigger...here Intent receiver threw an exception  And I can see the NullPointerException  here

Comment: Sorry. Do you mean to say that you tested the code above and managed to receive an NPE, that's why you are suggesting the null checking? :)

Comment: I see. You could've mentioned that in your post though. :)

Comment: @trigger...as per my knowledge, here except NPE, his code is right...that why I suggested him to do null checking

Comment: @trigger..at my side also byte array is not coming until i change getByteArray To getByteArrayExtra

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you posted in the comments

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

it looks like error is at `bitmap.compress` line which means that the bitmap that you are getting this way is null.

```
Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(userId);
```

That is why it gives an error when calling bitmap.compress. Try checking this function, you can also put debugger to confirm.